# Spark Window function using more than one column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe that shows the send time and the open time for each user:

```
val df = Seq(("user1", "2018-04-05 15:00:00", "2018-04-05 15:50:00"),
             ("user1", "2018-04-05 16:00:00", "2018-04-05 16:50:00"),
             ("user1", "2018-04-05 17:00:00", "2018-04-05 17:50:00"),
             ("user1", "2018-04-05 18:00:00", "2018-04-05 18:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 15:00:00", "2018-04-05 15:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 16:00:00", "2018-04-05 16:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 17:00:00", "2018-04-05 17:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 17:30:00", "2018-04-05 17:40:00"),             
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 18:00:00", null),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 19:00:00", null)              
            ).toDF("id", "sendTime", "openTime")
```

```
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|   id|           sendTime|           openTime|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|user1|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|
|user1|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|
|user1|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|
|user1|2018-04-05 18:00:00|2018-04-05 18:50:00|
|user2|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|
|user2|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|
|user2|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|
|user2|2018-04-05 17:30:00|2018-04-05 17:40:00|
|user2|2018-04-05 18:00:00|               null|
|user2|2018-04-05 19:00:00|               null|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Now I want to count the number of opens that have happened in the past two hours from each send time for each user. I used window function to partition by user, but I couldn't figure out how to compare values from the `sendTime` column to the `openTime` column. The result dataframe should look like this:

```
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|   id|           sendTime|           openTime|count|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|user1|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|    0|
|user1|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|    1|
|user1|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|    2|
|user1|2018-04-05 18:00:00|2018-04-05 18:50:00|    2|
|user2|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|    0|
|user2|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|    1|
|user2|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|    2|
|user2|2018-04-05 17:30:00|2018-04-05 17:40:00|    2|
|user2|2018-04-05 18:00:00|               null|    3|
|user2|2018-04-05 19:00:00|               null|    2|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

This is as far as I have got but doesn't give me what I need:

```
var df2 = df.withColumn("sendUnix", F.unix_timestamp($"sendTime")).withColumn("openUnix", F.unix_timestamp($"openTime"))
val w = Window.partitionBy($"id").orderBy($"sendUnix").rangeBetween(-2*60*60, 0)
df2 = df2.withColumn("count", F.count($"openUnix").over(w))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems quite difficult yo do with just using `Window` functions because you cannot reference the upper limit of `sendTime` when trying to derive whether the value from `openTime` is within the last 2 hours of the upper limit `sendTime`.

With spark 2.4 came higher order functions which you can read about here (https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html). Using these you could collect all the `openTime` within a window using the `collect_list` function and then using the higher order function `filter` filter out the `openTimes` outside the two hours prior to the `sendTime`. Finally you can count the values remaining in the list to give you the count that you are after. Here is my code for doing this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(("user1", "2018-04-05 15:00:00", "2018-04-05 15:50:00"),
             ("user1", "2018-04-05 16:00:00", "2018-04-05 16:50:00"),
             ("user1", "2018-04-05 17:00:00", "2018-04-05 17:50:00"),
             ("user1", "2018-04-05 18:00:00", "2018-04-05 18:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 15:00:00", "2018-04-05 15:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 16:00:00", "2018-04-05 16:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 17:00:00", "2018-04-05 17:50:00"),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 17:30:00", "2018-04-05 17:40:00"),             
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 18:00:00", null),
             ("user2", "2018-04-05 19:00:00", null)              
            ).toDF("id", "sendTime", "openTime")

var df2 = df.withColumn("sendUnix", unix_timestamp($"sendTime"))
            .withColumn("openUnix", unix_timestamp($"openTime"))

val df3 = df2.withColumn("opened", collect_list($"openUnix").over(w))

df3.show(false)

+-----+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
|id   |sendTime           |openTime           |sendUnix  |openUnix  |opened                              |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+
|user1|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|1522936800|1522939800|[1522939800]                        |
|user1|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|1522940400|1522943400|[1522943400, 1522939800]            |
|user1|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|1522944000|1522947000|[1522947000, 1522943400, 1522939800]|
|user1|2018-04-05 18:00:00|2018-04-05 18:50:00|1522947600|1522950600|[1522950600, 1522947000, 1522943400]|
|user2|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|1522936800|1522939800|[1522939800]                        |
|user2|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|1522940400|1522943400|[1522943400, 1522939800]            |
|user2|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|1522944000|1522947000|[1522947000, 1522943400, 1522939800]|
|user2|2018-04-05 17:30:00|2018-04-05 17:40:00|1522945800|1522946400|[1522946400, 1522947000, 1522943400]|
|user2|2018-04-05 18:00:00|null               |1522947600|null      |[1522946400, 1522947000, 1522943400]|
|user2|2018-04-05 19:00:00|null               |1522951200|null      |[1522946400, 1522947000]            |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+------------------------------------+

val df4 = df3.selectExpr("id", "sendTime", "openTime", "sendUnix", "openUnix",
        "size(filter(opened, x -> x < sendUnix AND  x > sendUnix - 7200)) as count")

df4.show(false)

+-----+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
|id   |sendTime           |openTime           |sendUnix  |openUnix  |count|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
|user1|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|1522936800|1522939800|0    |
|user1|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|1522940400|1522943400|1    |
|user1|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|1522944000|1522947000|2    |
|user1|2018-04-05 18:00:00|2018-04-05 18:50:00|1522947600|1522950600|2    |
|user2|2018-04-05 15:00:00|2018-04-05 15:50:00|1522936800|1522939800|0    |
|user2|2018-04-05 16:00:00|2018-04-05 16:50:00|1522940400|1522943400|1    |
|user2|2018-04-05 17:00:00|2018-04-05 17:50:00|1522944000|1522947000|2    |
|user2|2018-04-05 17:30:00|2018-04-05 17:40:00|1522945800|1522946400|1    |
|user2|2018-04-05 18:00:00|null               |1522947600|null      |3    |
|user2|2018-04-05 19:00:00|null               |1522951200|null      |2    |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Looks great! There is only a small problem with this that has caused the count on three rows from the bottom to be different from the expected response that I have posted. This is due to `rangeBetween(-2*60*60, 0)` in my code, that apparently you have also used. This leads to including only Sends that are only two hours before the current Send Time, whereas we need to look at all Send times and just look at the opens that are two hours before. If you remove the `rangeBetween(-2*60*60, 0)` I think we get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("sendTimeStamp", unix_timestamp(col("sendTime"))).withColumn("openTimeStamp", unix_timestamp(col("openTime")))
    
val w = Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('sendTimeStamp).rangeBetween(-7200, 0)

var df2 = df1.withColumn("list", collect_list('openTimeStamp).over(w))

var df3 = df2.select('*, explode('list).as("prevTimeStamp"))

df3.groupBy('id, 'sendTime).agg(max('openTime).as("openTime"), sum(when(col("sendTimeStamp").minus(col("prevTimeStamp")).between(0, 7200), 1).otherwise(0)).as("count")).show
```